# Obtaining Inner HTML From Iframe Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a project, in that I want to show the data from a website in the form of a table. So I can do the process in the child window iframe and get the table content from the child window to the parent window. All are working fine, But this will work all browsers except ie. and it won't display any errors, One friend gives the answer ( http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/
) for this but it shows the Error "Access denied", Please help me.

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540077

Answer (score 2):

It is because the site you are referencing in the iframe is on another domain.  In your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540077/javascript/540115#540115) that I responded to, I misunderstood and thought you said they were on the same domain.  Quoting another forum:
"As the i-frame is from a different website you cannot read any of the inner properties of the i-frame."
[http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Application_Servers/Java/Apache_Tomcat/Q_22843851.html]

I don't know that what you are doing is even possible, but if it is, I'm sure someone on here can help.