# Getting contents of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to get the contents of an `<iframe>` from another page.

The other page is a different website; I'm logged into that website and I get its contents and store it in the `<iframe>`.

How do I get the contents of that `<iframe>` into the current window ?

Comment: double dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540077 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540189, please stop re-asking.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: you can not do it. Browsers restrict the interaction between content from different websites using the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: I guess you meant can NOT do it? As you explain why it won't work in the next sentence.

Comment: Nice catch. Yes, I left out the not part :-)